# DAG shortest path with weight on vertex/node in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, directed-acyclic-graphs

[image: weighted pie chart]This is a slight variation on many existing algorithms, whereby topological sort seems to be the most obvious and efficient answer.

Lets take an example to explain more clearly what I mean.

I have a DAG starting at vertex A with 5 vertex/nodes to E.   I want to find the shortest path from A to E such that each node itself is weighted along with the path, at some point there is the possibility each node could have more than 1 weighted value.  The Nodes could have many variables, such as x, y and z.  These inputs are weighted based on some preference for example user preference.  So y could we be weighted more heavily than x or z and this takes into account the "shorter" path.

I have attached an image to explain what I want to do.  What's the best way of achieving this?  The reason for adding weight to nodes, is preference of a particular node by a given input.

In the pie chart we can see that Y is weighted most heavily with 50% preference, therefore we would Y*N where N is the number to calculate weight.  In D in the attached Graph, x, y z would be {1, 0.6, 0.3}

Edit: Based on original answer, updating the description.  Simplified the diagram and added a new pie chart to explain the weighting.

Comment: Note: [google-guava has a nice java graph library](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/package-summary.html) that has options for directed and weighted/valued (simple or complex weights/values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With directed graphs it is easy to deal with weights on the nodes. The common approach is the following:

1. Split each node V into two nodes V' and V"
2. Add an edge from V' to V" with weight equal to the weight of the node
3. For each inbound edge (U, V) add a new edge in the graph from U" to V' with the same weight
4. For each outbound edge (V, T) add a new edge in the graph from V" to T' with the same weight

Now you've reduced the problem to a shortest path problem in a 'regular' DAG and you should know how to solve it.

It is not clear what you mean by multiple weights in your questions but there are two options:

- If what you mean is that you can choose any of the weights at the node simply use the smallest one when adding the edge V'->V"
- If the weights are cumulative, simply add them when adding the edge V'->V"

Comment: For example in the above graph, node C could have {3, 5} weights.  where  for example say x = 3(cost) and y = 5(duration), variables, both weighted equally.

Comment: So what is the cost of passing through the node then?

Comment: Good question.  Slight more complexity, say we weight the variables at a given node x, y, z three variables with weight ordered y, x, z , then for node a -> b or a->c is the difference between b(y , x , z ) and c(y, x, z) such that b(y) is less than c(y) etc.  For example b(2, 4, 1) and c(1, 4, 2)  cumulative figure is 7, but B(y) is weighted greater than c(y) therefore A->B node is shorter path.

Comment: @pronane please edit your question and try to explain how multiple weights work. Your example above makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Edge(String startPoint, string EndPoint, int distance, int [] valueOther) {
    Distance=weight 
    ValueOther=Time{6am10, 6am30, 7am....}
    weight = distance + timewait + valueOther
}
```